# React app with express server shows just blanc page

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, package.json

I have one page react app without routing. It works fine. Now I'm trying to host it on heroku, that's why I addded express server. I run server with 'node server/server.js', and after that i was trying to vizit http://localhost:3000 I see just blanc page without errors. I tryed to run app on heroku, but got the same result.
In page code I see just div "root" and it is empty, but inside should be rendered div "app".

My server

```
const path = require('path');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const publicPath = path.join(__dirname, '../', 'public');
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.use(express.static(publicPath));
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(publicPath, 'index.html'));
});
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log('Server is up!');
});
```

my package.json

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "homepage": "https://reaweapp.herokuapp.com/",
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.11.0",
    "@material-ui/lab": "^4.0.0-alpha.56",
    "@material/textfield": "^5.1.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server/server.js",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d build"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "gh-pages": "^3.1.0"
  }
}
```

my index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
serviceWorker.register();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have 1 extra dot in "../" and would need to path to the build instead:

```
const publicPath = path.join(__dirname, './','build');
```

An alternative to doing it yourself would be to use the serve package

```
npm i serve --save
```

and change scripts in package.json to

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "react-scripts start",
    "start": "serve -s build",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "heroku-postbuild": "npm run build"
  },
```